issubclass() arg 1 TypeError when importing langchain_openai
Hi I'm working inside Jupyter Notebook.
I run into the following errors when I tried to run
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
The notebook ran successfully on another computer so I'm not sure if some dependencies got messed up.
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 10>()
      8 from urllib.parse import urlparse
      9 from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
---> 10 from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
     11 from langchain.schema import HumanMessage, SystemMessage, AIMessage
     13 blocked_sites = []

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain_openai\__init__.py:1, in <module>
----> 1 from langchain_openai.chat_models import AzureChatOpenAI, ChatOpenAI
      2 from langchain_openai.embeddings import AzureOpenAIEmbeddings, OpenAIEmbeddings
      3 from langchain_openai.llms import AzureOpenAI, OpenAI

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain_openai\chat_models\__init__.py:1, in <module>
----> 1 from langchain_openai.chat_models.azure import AzureChatOpenAI
      2 from langchain_openai.chat_models.base import ChatOpenAI
      4 __all__ = ["ChatOpenAI", "AzureChatOpenAI"]

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain_openai\chat_models\azure.py:24, in <module>
      8 from typing import (
      9     Any,
     10     Callable,
   (...)
     20     overload,
     21 )
     23 import openai
---> 24 from langchain_core.language_models import LanguageModelInput
     25 from langchain_core.language_models.chat_models import LangSmithParams
     26 from langchain_core.messages import BaseMessage

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\__init__.py:40, in <module>
      1 """**Language Model** is a type of model that can generate text or complete
      2 text prompts.
      3 
   (...)
     37 https://python.langchain.com/v0.2/docs/how_to/custom_llm/
     38 """  # noqa: E501
---> 40 from langchain_core.language_models.base import (
     41     BaseLanguageModel,
     42     LangSmithParams,
     43     LanguageModelInput,
     44     LanguageModelLike,
     45     LanguageModelOutput,
     46     get_tokenizer,
     47 )
     48 from langchain_core.language_models.chat_models import BaseChatModel, SimpleChatModel
     49 from langchain_core.language_models.fake import FakeListLLM, FakeStreamingListLLM

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain_core\language_models\base.py:24, in <module>
     21 from typing_extensions import TypeAlias, TypedDict
     23 from langchain_core._api import deprecated
---> 24 from langchain_core.messages import (
     25     AnyMessage,
     26     BaseMessage,
     27     MessageLikeRepresentation,
     28     get_buffer_string,
     29 )
     30 from langchain_core.prompt_values import PromptValue
     31 from langchain_core.pydantic_v1 import BaseModel, Field, validator

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain_core\messages\__init__.py:18, in <module>
      1 """**Messages** are objects used in prompts and chat conversations.
      2 
      3 **Class hierarchy:**
   (...)
     15 
     16 """  # noqa: E501
---> 18 from langchain_core.messages.ai import (
     19     AIMessage,
     20     AIMessageChunk,
     21 )
     22 from langchain_core.messages.base import (
     23     BaseMessage,
     24     BaseMessageChunk,
   (...)
     27     messages_to_dict,
     28 )
     29 from langchain_core.messages.chat import ChatMessage, ChatMessageChunk

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain_core\messages\ai.py:11, in <module>
      4 from typing_extensions import TypedDict
      6 from langchain_core.messages.base import (
      7     BaseMessage,
      8     BaseMessageChunk,
      9     merge_content,
     10 )
---> 11 from langchain_core.messages.tool import (
     12     InvalidToolCall,
     13     ToolCall,
     14     ToolCallChunk,
     15     default_tool_chunk_parser,
     16     default_tool_parser,
     17 )
     18 from langchain_core.messages.tool import (
     19     invalid_tool_call as create_invalid_tool_call,
     20 )
     21 from langchain_core.messages.tool import (
     22     tool_call as create_tool_call,
     23 )

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\langchain_core\messages\tool.py:10, in <module>
      6 from langchain_core.messages.base import BaseMessage, BaseMessageChunk, merge_content
      7 from langchain_core.utils._merge import merge_dicts, merge_obj
---> 10 class ToolMessage(BaseMessage):
     11     """Message for passing the result of executing a tool back to a model.
     12 
     13     ToolMessages contain the result of a tool invocation. Typically, the result
   (...)
     48     to request multiple tool calls in parallel.
     49     """  # noqa: E501
     51     tool_call_id: str

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pydantic\main.py:205, in pydantic.main.ModelMetaclass.__new__()

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pydantic\fields.py:491, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.infer()

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pydantic\fields.py:421, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.__init__()

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pydantic\fields.py:537, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.prepare()

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pydantic\fields.py:641, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._type_analysis()

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\typing.py:852, in _SpecialGenericAlias.__subclasscheck__(self, cls)
    850     return issubclass(cls.__origin__, self.__origin__)
    851 if not isinstance(cls, _GenericAlias):
--> 852     return issubclass(cls, self.__origin__)
    853 return super().__subclasscheck__(cls)

TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class```



I've tried to reinstall the following libraries but I still encounter the same error:
`pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall openai langchain pydantic pydantic-core`

I encountered the same TypeError again. 

Hope to get some guidance on this, thank you.


Looks like there are two paths to different libraries. Your openai and other modules are picked up from ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\
And the error lib typing is in C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\
I would recommend install typing in the env where you are running your code:
pip install typing

Thank you so much for your kind help!
I encountered a new error after I had pip install typing but I'm now able to import ChatOpenAI. Our of curiosity, would you know why this error came up even though the import now worked? Due to the character limit, I'll split the error message into multiple replies.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:      command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-uvgwa890\\typing_9631894aa0dd4c7ca6adf6c34b8fe4fa\\setup.py'"'"'; 

    ImportError: cannot import name 'tarfile' from 'backports' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\backports\__init__.py)

WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/d9/6eebe19d46bd05360c9a9aae822e67a80f9242aabbfc58b641b957546607/typing-3.7.4.3.tar.gz#sha256=1187fb9c82fd670d10aa07bbb6cfcfe4bdda42d6fab8d5134f04e8c4d0b71cc9 (from https://pypi.org/simple/typing/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.```
